# Cambiar directorio en ImageField(upload_to)

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando un modelo que incluye la carga de una imagen en el directorio `documents/`. Habrá alguna forma de utilizar los mismo campos `name` y `lastname` como ruta para guardar la imagen. ¿Que sea por ejemplo `"documents/pedro_perez/"`?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="nombre")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="apellido")
    document_id = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/',verbose_name="Identificación oficial"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes hacerlo, extendiendo la funcionalidad de `upload_to`.

De la siguiente manera:

```
def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return f'documents/{ instance.name }_{ instance.lastname }/' + filename

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="nombre")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="apellido")
    document_id = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to,verbose_name="Identificación oficial",)
```

Asi dara el resultado que buscas de acuerdo a los campos `name` y `lastname`.

Si estas mas interesado y quieres profundisar en el tema te sugiero revisar la documentacion oficial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to